# How to access the parent page elements of an Iframe in C#?

Tags: c#, iframe, parent, modalpopupextender

I have a Modal popup extender in parent page and I am showing another page in an iframe (inside the parent page).
How can I access parent page controls from iframe page, I have been doing this:

```
 ModalPopupExtender Modal = (ModalPopupExtender)Parent.FindControl("General_ModalPopupExtender");
```

But no success.